# Showing progress of async method that is downloading data from a WCF service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I'm trying to show the progress of a method where I am loading data from my WCF service to my WPF application.

I have about 1500 lines of data in a table that I want to load into a datagrid, but it takes quite a while to load the data and I want to show the user the progress of the download so that they know how long it's going to take.

Here is my coding so far:

This is my method where I load the data from my WCF service

```
private async Task UpdateStockAsync()
{
    using (TruckServiceClient service = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        var allStock = await service.GetSysproStockAsync();
        dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = allStock.Select(x =>
        new AllStock
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            ...
            MaterialThickness = x.MaterialThickness
        }).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Here is where I call my `UpdateStockAsync` method from a window loaded event

```
    private void SysproStock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() => UpdateStockAsync());
    }
```

How would I be possible to show the status of the the download in a progressbar?

Comment: The possible solution is to  add additional wcf service that will provide the amount of data(lines, size etc) that can  be downloaded. Than after you start receiving data you can calculate progress based on the amount of received data and amount of data that still need to  be received.

Comment: Why are you using Task.Run when you can just have an async handler and use await instead? Using Task.Run this way is not really a good idea, because you're blocking a thread pool thread.

[Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run for the Wrong Thing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html)

Comment: @VitaliyK That sounds really good! And thanks for the comment :) I can already get the amount of data from the WPF like: `int amount = allStock.Count();`. It loads instantly from the WCF to the WPF...but It still takes about 2-3 minutes to show all of the data in the datagrid for some reason.

Comment: @KerimEmurla I used Async/Await, but then I cannot access any of my UI for some strange reason. It freezes it completely until only after the download is complete

Comment: @KerimEmurla And I cannot add `await` inside of my `Dispatcher.Invoke` in any way either.

Comment: @CareTaker22 , do you even need Dispatcher.Invoke when using await?

Comment: @KerimEmurla No sir. I've just tested and removed it. Thanks for asking. I hadn't used async/await yet in my previous coding, so I forgot to test and remove it :)